# Azure AD Windows logins connected to G Suite accounts

Tags: windows, g-suite, entra-id, microsoft-intune

We use G Suite for our email, cloud storage, calendars, etc, but use Windows computers (mostly).

I've read a bit about Azure AD and the possibilities of linking G Suite accounts to Azure accounts so that essentially users can log into their Windows 10 machines with their G Suite credentials, but am pretty new to all this.

Is there a way, as well as using Google credentials to log into Windows 10, to also centrally manage the software on the Windows machine remotely, IE install new printer drivers, deploy new local software, manage Windows Updates, etc.

Is Microsoft Intune related to managing Windows software deployment?

On top of that, when a user logs into Windows with their Google credentials can the Downloads and Desktop folders be synced with their GDrive account so these files can be transferred between machines? It isn't often that users switch machines, but occasionally it is necessary.

I'm pretty new to all this, so it might be a stupid question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can log in to Windows using your G Suite account [since January 2020](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2020/01/windows-10-gsuite-admin-single-sign-on-sso.html). This also includes device management.